# Star collision observation

Tags: collision, stars

What would these scenarios look like in real world? I mean, what the result would be?:

- 2 stars (not necessarily same mass) will collide "side by side", like in, they originally were traveling parallelly, but their gravity set them on collision course...
- Collision again, but this time will be a full head on collision
- another collision, but this time a angled head on...

In any case, will they merge? would they both be destroyed? Have we ever watched such event?

Comment: There have been some numerical models of stellar collisions (e.g., [this site at Allegheny U](http://starsmasher.allegheny.edu/jalombar/movies/)); however these models typically assume the stars are in a [binary system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star).

Comment: This happens and has been observed.  Try searching the slate.com/badastronomy blogs, as Phil Plait has written about stars "eating each other"